# What is the thevenin equivalent?

Tags: thevenin

[image]

I tried the test current source followed by nodal analysis  and it worked.

But when I proceed to find the Vth followed by shorting A & B and then finding short circuit  current I am unable to proceed as I am stuck at the Vth!

Can someone please  enlighten me?

I assume I m terribly wrong at some concept!

Please share all possible methods of solving this one.

Thank you.

Comment: Your approach is correct. First, solve for the short-circuit current between terminals A & B. Then solve for the open-circuit potential between A & B. Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: First the short circuit current and then open circuit potential?
I thought it was the other way round. Getting stuck at Vth.

Comment: For short circuit you draw a wire between A & B (which means you can neglect the 8 Ohm resistor for that case), the short circuit current is the current through that wire. Open circuit you solve the circuit as is, have you made any attempts at this problem?

Comment: The two cases are solved independently, so you can proceed in any order you choose. Solution for Isc is simpler than Voc.

Comment: @G2G it shouldn't matter if you find the short circuit current and then open circuit potential or open circuit potential and then short circuit current. Just as long as you aren't trying to find the short circuit potential or open-circuit current ...

Comment: Yes I have tried it. I am unable to find open circuit voltage Vth.

Comment: If Ix is going through the 6 ohm, where's the remaining 0.5Ix going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to determine the parameters you want. I like to use superposition, especially with controlled sources. Unlike the popular belief, superposition works with controlled sources as described [here](https://leachlegacy.ece.gatech.edu/papers/superpos.pdf). The trick is to determine the controlling variable first, \$I_x\$ in your case. When applying superposition, sources (controlled or independent) must alternatively be reduced to 0:a 0-A current source becomes an open circuit while a 0-V voltage source becomes a short circuit. However, when setting a controlled source to 0, its controlling variable is kept untouched. See the below sketch to determine the controlling current \$I_x\$:
[image]
From the upper sketch, you have \$I_x=\frac{V_1}{R_1+R_2+R_3}\$. From the lower sketch, you set the 12-V source to 0 and end up with a simple configuration in which you can apply the current divider law: \$I_x=1.5I_x\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2+R_3}\$. Now sum these two expressions and solve for \$I_x\$. You should find \$I_x=\frac{V_1}{R_2-0.5R_1+R_3}\$. With your values, you have 1.333 A. Having determined \$I_x\$, you see that \$V_{th}=I_xR_3=1.333\;A\times8\;\Omega=10.667\;V\$.
The short-circuit current is also determined using a similar approach:
[image]
Applying superposition, we have: \$I_x=\frac{V_1}{R_1+R_2}+1.5I_x\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}\$. Solving for \$I_x\$ and realizing that \$I_x\$ is actually your short-circuit current, you have: \$I_{sc}=\frac{V_1}{R_2-0.5R_1}=12\;A\$. The Thévenin output resistance is thus \$R_{th}=\frac{V_{th}}{I_{sc}}=\frac{10.667}{12}=0.889\;\Omega\$. The equivalent circuit is thus drawn as follows:
[image]

The calculation file is here:
[image]
I have simulated the circuit to obtain the dc operating point. The output impedance requires a dynamic approach by connecting a 1-A current source across \$R_3\$ and using a .TF command:
[image]

The superposition theorem applied to dependent sources is really cool. The thing is to understand that the controlling variable, \$I_x\$ in your example, must NOT be set to 0 during superposition. It is the controlled source that is 0. The controlling variable must first be evaluated before proceeding with the calculations. You have videos on YouTube showing how to apply the extension of the original superposition theorem.